# Bypass/Ignore Exchange Server "Maximum Send Size"?

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, exchange-server

**As soon as possible I will start a bounty and award 150 (that's what I have) points for solution.**

I am developing Outlook add in. When message is sent, add in processes the message, it removes the attachments and sends them through different transfer channel and puts the attachment download links in message body.

When using outlook with exchange server with "maximum send size" limit users can't even attach large files to message. Outlook displays a warning that imposes exchange limit.

To make it worse attachment is refused before any of attachment events are fired.

I need a way to bypass this behavior. Something that will allow users to add attachments of any size by using outlook paper clip button, or drag and drop. Or good direction I can work on.

**Adding separate attach button is not an option.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the `PR_MAX_SUBMIT_MESSAGE_SIZE` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x666D0003`) using `Store.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`.

I was able to set it using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - click `IMsgStore` button, right click, select `IMAPIProp::GetProps`, type `PR_MAX_SUBMIT_MESSAGE_SIZE` - the property is not shown by default, then double click to modify it. I don't know if Outlook will overwrite it on the local cached store later - I never tried to set that property.

Note that the limit is there for a reason - Exchange won't let you send the message if it is over the limit. But it will work if you simply want to get rid of the warming because you will handle the attachment on your own when the message is sent.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, by design.  The limit is enforced in the message store to which the submit operation is sent.  You could zip the attachment, or chunk it up into separate emails, to allow very large data to be sent.

Comment: How can I zip it if I can even get it from add in code? If I was able to process it at all, I would replace it with placeholder of smaller size and do other kind of nice things but its blocked before add in is notified about attachment.

Comment: As I recall, the act of attaching triggers this check. Sorry this is not the answer you want but that's how it works, otherwise the admin limit would be meaningless.  fyi I worked on Exchange Server, though not the message store, for several years.

Comment: Steve, I am sorry. My comment sounds little rude. Be sure that I didn't want to show disrespect. I'm in big mess atm and comment went out unpolished. It was more like thinking loud. :)

Comment: I did not take it that way, be assured ;-)  thinking out loud is what comments are for.